# Responsive Table CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my table

[image]

I want to display the above table for mobile responsive like in css

[image]

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Just google it. you will get lots of links showing how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is what you are trying to accomplish, but try using the viewport-width unit vm.

```
.responsive-table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width:100%;
  font-size:2vw;
 }
.responsive-table th{background-color:red;color:white;padding:5px}
```

Here is a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/f5c93LL2/

It will scale the font down relative to the viewport-width so the table will look relatively the same on every screen, provided the browser supports the vw unit.